# Почему нельзя сделать Alter Table и добавить Identity к существующей колонке?

Tags: sql, sql-server

В общем решил скопировать таблицы из одной БД в другую БД на сервере.

Воспользовался я стандартной утилитой `Export/Import`.

К моему удивлению не были скопированы не ключи, не ограничения, не индексы...

Но так как имелись исходные таблицы, я сгенерировал скрипты и все вернул на место.

Позже я обнаружил, что `IDENTITY` не был скопирован. Сначала я попробовал добавить  его через интерфейс, на что я получил ошибку `TIMEOUT`. Казалось бы, что может быть проще навесить `IDENTITY` на `PRIMARY KEY`, но нет...

Погуглив, я обнаружил, что через `Alter Table` его добавить нельзя.

**На выбор было:**

1)Добавить новую колонку с `IDENTITY` и забыть про старую. Данный вариант мне не подошел, так как колонка являлась PK и на нее были ссылки=> сгенерив новый `IDENTITY` можно было бы что-то потерять.

2)Создать новую таблицу, где уже есть `IDENTITY` и с использованием `IDENTITY INSERT` слить данные со старой таблицы. Чем я и воспользовался, потеряв дополнительное время.

Подскажите, с чем связаны такие ограничения?

Или все таки можно как-нибудь через `ALTER TABLE` добавить `IDENTITYT`?

Comment: Есть возможность через создать скрипт таблицы со всеми объектами. Нужно только не забыть их указать. Список того что нужно включать доступен по кнопке "дополнительно".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить IDENTITY через ALTER TABLE никак нельзя - это общее место, к Майкрософту не раз обращались с такими просьбами, но, к сожалению, возможность так и не реализовали. С чем это связано - достоверно неизвестно, возможно, команда разработчиков сможет дать ответ.

Вполне вероятно, возможность до сих пор не добавлена в связи с тем, что IDENTITY теперь считается устаревшим способом получения новых значений - начиная с SQL Server 2012 реализованы последовательности (SEQUENCE) - с ними работать несколько проще и, в том числе, реализуем нужный вам сценарий - SEQUENCE не зашивается в таблицу, на таблицу добавляется DEFAULT CONSTRAINT с получением данных из SEQUENCE, вот такой командой:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mySequence 
    AS int
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
GO

ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT IdSequence DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR mySequence) 
        FOR Id;
```

Comment: _"IDENTITY теперь считается устаревшим способом"_ ой, ой, ну уж, ну уж ...

Comment: Ну технически то нет, иначе он был бы объявлен deprecated, чего пока не произошло. Так что, согласен, эта фраза не совсем корректна. Правильнее было бы сказать, что SEQUENCE - это **еще один** способ получения последовательности, который лучше подходит в некоторых случаях.